# csh set: no match error wildcard

Tags: arrays, set, glob, csh, no-match

trying to look up files in directories with wildcard *, and put the names into an array

the files have similar names (MATCHr1, MATCHr2 ... )

the problem arises when the file does not exist (which is a possibility)

set command returns a "no match" error and terminates the loop

if this happens how can i get it handle the error by jumping to the next iteration?

```
set SUBIDS = (10003 10005 10006)

foreach SUBID ($SUBIDS)

foreach SEQR ( MATCH ENC NBACK SIMON FACE )

ls -l  *${SEQR}*.nii.gz

set Array = *${SEQR}*.nii.gz

echo $Array[*]
```

....rest of code works to use contents of Array to create text files 
and works great when the `*${SEQR}*.nii.gz` returns a file name

but fails when the no matches are made with the wildcard

Any help would be well apreciated

thanks!

Comment: try adding a check on array size after you define it (`if #$Array >0`)

Comment: where ?      `ls -l  *${SEQR}*.nii.gz` returns: no match but  allows code to continue onto `set Array = *${SEQR}*.nii.gz` which also returns no match but the script exits and does not continue to next `SEQR`

Comment: you can do you ls and check the $status (or $STATUS, depends on your system) flag: `ls -l *${SEQR}*.nii.gz >> /dev/null ; if !$status then ...` i'm not next to my machine now to check the exact syntax, but that's the spirit of it...

Comment: that did it!      `ls -l  *${SEQR}*.nii.gz  >> /dev/null`      `# compensate for no match error`      `set checkme = $status`      `# if return good`     `if ( $checkme == 0 ) then ....`     THANKS!

Comment: I'm turning my answer to an official answer so you'll be able to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do you ls and check the $status (or $STATUS, depends on your system) flag:
`ls -l *${SEQR}*.nii.gz >> /dev/null ; if !$status then ...`