# csh - suppress STDERR when using backticks

Tags: stdout, stderr, csh, backticks

I'd like to write a bit of code that looks like this:

```
while ( `ls -1 ${JOB_PREFIX}_${job_counter}_*.out | wc -l` > 0 )
   echo "Do something here." 
end
```

But every time there is no `ls -1 ${JOB_PREFIX}_${job_counter}*.csh` it gives an annoying  `ls: No match.`

Is it possible to suppress this error message but still pipe `STDOUT` to `wc` ? I went through the existing questions on this but most of the answers are either not working on `csh` or tries to combine `STDOUT` and `STDERR` with `|&` which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would have been to mute the `ls` itself, but it is not possible.
You can suppress your entire script, meaning:
If your loops is in a file called `myscript.cs` and you call your file with some args `myscript.cs -arg1 blabla -arg2 bla`, add >& to your shell command to redirect stderr to wherever you want. e.g.
`myscript.cs -arg1 blabla -arg2 bla >& /dev/null`

It's not answering your answer directly, but it should solve your problem.

**Edit**
Since the comment added that the script should be redirected to another script, you can split your line to two lines:

> if `ls -1 ${JOB_PREFIX}_${job_counter}_*.out >& /dev/null` then
>     while < your while here >
>   end
>   endif

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem as the output of the script piped to another script and also sent to a log file, all of which will then have the same problem. I'd really like a solution that would suppress `ls` in effect.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261228/csh-set-no-match-error-wildcard/42384620#42384620 I answered there on a very similar question

Answer (score 0):

csh and tcsh cannot redirect stderr by itself, one of many reasons you should not use it for scripting.

If you're okay with spawning another shell, you can change `JOB_COUNTER` into an environment variable and do:

```
while ( `sh -c '2>/dev/null ls -1 ${JOB_PREFIX}_${JOB_COUNTER}_*.out | wc -l'` > 0 )
   echo "Do something here." 
end
```

If you want to use a test as a condition in a `while` loop instead of an expression, you have to get creative.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
set i = 4
while ( 1 )
    if ( $i <= 0 ) break 
    echo hi
    @ i = ($i - 1)
end
```

In your case, this might look something like: I changed the `wc -l` to a `grep -q .` so that we can use the exit status instead of the result printed to stderr.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

set dir_exit_status = 0
while ( $dir_exit_status = 0 )
    ( ls -1 ${JOB_PREFIX}_${job_counter}_*.out | grep -q '.') >& /dev/null
    set dir_exit_status = $status
end
```